# look for Column heading and sum up

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working with a excel file with a lot of data, which is arranged in 2 sheets.

I would like to get data from sheet 1 to sheet 2 with reference to the column headings.
For example:

[image: table]

So if I want to find the sum of function 1 person A with criteria 1, the command have to go and find the heading "sum of function 1" in sheet 1 and choose the data that are only under criteria 1 and sum it up in sheet 2 cell D5. (By using column heading reference instead of cell reference). 
The table range is A2 : U80.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to format your data as table (select the data -> Menu Insert -> Table). Then you rename your table, for example Table1. Let's say one of the columns you want to sum on the sheet2 is called ColumnName.
On the sheet 2 you write a formula

```
=SUM(Table1[ColumnName])
```

The result will be what you are after.

Comment: hi i have made some changes in the question have a look thnks @Mladen

Answer (score 0):

You should try it by SUMIFS(). Syntax will be

```
=SUMIFS(AgeRange from sheet1,NameRange Sheet1, Name cell Sheet2, PlaceRangeSh1, Place Cell Sh2)
```

Tell me if requires further help.

Comment: hii, @SawanGarg Thanks for the help, i have modified my question to provide more infos ,have a look thnks